# Intermittent issue when viewing PDF files

Tags: c#-4.0, pdf, pdfsharp

I have a weird problem with viewing PDF files.

I have a menu button on a windows forms application that opens up a form with a PDF viewer. This works absolutely perfectly in the majority of cases, however I have one user who is experiencing problems.

It seems to work but them it will suddenly refuse to load the document and just shows a grey screen. She also has problems when printing from this form.

I have investigated this issue and I cant reproduce this is the dev environment.

The only possible reason I can see is that she is using something called "Nitro reader" rather than the standard Adobe viewers which we tested on.

Could this be the cause of this intermittent error or are there other known issues with the PDF viewer in C#?

I know this question is a long shot but I am hoping someone else will have come across a similar issue.

I am using .net 4 with VS2010 and I am using PDF sharp to generate the document.

Thanks

Comment: Is this linked to particular PDF documents? Or can the UI be reloaded and will the same document than work? (in other words, could it be that Nitro has problems with some of the PDF documents you serve?)

Comment: It is possible, In true IT support style I asked her to "turn it off and on again" and it solved the problem, however I am concerned about the underlying cause. She has tried with many other documents throughout the application with similar results, I am thinking that i is Nitro that is the problem as everyone else is using Adobe but I still concerned that it could be a coding issue or indicating a more serious error.

Comment: Have you tried Nitro support? (http://www.nitropdf.com) I used to know these guys years ago, they were actually very responsive at the time.

Comment: No I havent thanks for your help I shall try it now.